# How can I undo setting the PATH variable?

Tags: windows, cmd, path

I typed the below on the command line. How can I revert it?

```
PATH = 'c:/windows';'D:sass';
```

Comment: Did you put "SET" before it?

Comment: No. Just this: C:\nodejs\program 5\client>PATH = 'c:/windows';'D:sass';

Comment: See answer below ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just restart your cmd.exe, the variables are local to your command prompt.